# How to Synchronize Filters Settings?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, slider, cifilter

When I start adjusting the first slider, the settings of the second get lost. Is it possible to sync all parameters?

@IBAction func amountSliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

```
            let sliderValue = amountSlider.value
    
            filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
            filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter.setValue(sliderValue, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    
            context = CIContext(options:nil)
            
           let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: filter.outputImage!.extent)
            let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
            self.imageView.image = newImage
    
        }
```

@IBAction func exposureSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

```
            let sliderValue = exposureSlider.value
            filter = CIFilter(name:"CIVignette")!
            filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
            filter.setValue(sliderValue * 2, forKey:"inputIntensity")
            filter.setValue(sliderValue * 30, forKey:"inputRadius")
    
          context = CIContext(options:nil)
          
          let cgimg = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: filter.outputImage!.extent)
          let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
          self.imageView.image = newImage }
```

Comment: For both IBActions, you are starting from `beginImage`. Are you sure that this `beginImage` is updated with the changes made by any slider movement?

Answer (score 0):

You always need to apply both filters when either slider changes, e.g. by extracting the update into a function that you call in both `IBActions`:

```
func updateImage() {
    let brightnessValue = self.amountSlider.value
    let exposureValue = self.exposureSlider.value

    colorControlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    colorControlsFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    colorControlsFilter.setValue(brightnessValue, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    let colorControlsOutput = colorControlsFilter.outputImage!

    vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIVignette")!
    vignetteFilter.setValue(colorControlsOutput, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
    vignetteFilter.setValue(exposureValue * 2, forKey:"inputIntensity")
    vignetteFilter.setValue(exposureValue * 30, forKey:"inputRadius")
    let vignetteOutput = vignetteFilter.outputImage!

    // Don't create a CIContext every time! Init it once and re-use it.
    let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(vignetteOutput, from: vignetteOutput.extent)
    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
    self.imageView.image = newImage
}
```